# Não exibe os dados do relacionamento dentro do WITH

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um Relacionamento *Polymorphic* entre a Classe Cliente e Carro.

Classe Cliente:

```
public function carros()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Carro::class, 'dono');
}
```

Classe Carro:

```
public function dono()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Estou fazendo uma pesquisa e no resultado os dados do Dono aparecem como `NULL`.

```
$result=Carro::with('dono')->where('id',10)->get();
```

Agora se eu faço a pesquisa usando o `Thinker` os valores aparecem normalmente.
Onde eu estou errando para vir o `NULL` como resposta no DONO. Os valores do carro voltam certinhos.

Comment: Experimenta, `...where('id', 10)...`

Comment: Perdão foi a correção que adicionou o = aino where. Mas esta conforme você citou. Vou alterar. Obrigado.

Comment: O seu problema foi solucionado?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu li esta pergunta que você citou e acho que a minha não tem haver com ela.

Comment: Cara pra mim é duplicata, porque se não está carregando tem algo por tras que você fez de errado, veja a sua resposta mesmo já é um problema, se existe relação porque do where depois ???

Comment: @VirgilioNovic olha o Where é para eu selecionar um carro e depois de selecionado eu quero saber o seu dono. Não vejo erro algum no where.

Comment: A sua pergunta é confusa ... Se fala em.lista agora coloca o where na relação. Tudo isso não é o que a pergunta diz. Mas tudo bem resolveu seu problema .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu resolvi adicionando no select os campos de ligação com o relacionamento.

```
$result=Carro::with('dono')->select('dono_id','dono_type')->where('id',10)->get();
```

Não sei por que isto mas faz tudo funcionar certinho.